# How to store / access strapi dynamic/custom database config?

Tags: strapi

Am new to dev but loving it so far.

Having some challenges with creating / using custom database config in strapi. Dont quite understand the guide here: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/configurations.html#usage

Tried creating a .env file and also follow some tutorial examples to create a .tmp folder with the file, but doubt its correct.

[Screenshot of the files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJao2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but here is a thread on GitHub about this topic.

**https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3558**

Answer (score 0):

Strapi does not automatically load environment files for you. If you wish to do that, create a bootstrap file - this gets executed when strapi starts. For this to work, you'll need to install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). `npm install --save dotenv`

```
// yourrepo/api/config/functions/bootstrap.js
/**
 * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
 * your application gets started.
 *
 * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
 * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
 */

const dotenv = require('dotenv').config(); // load environment variables


module.exports = async () => {}
```

There are many ways to do it, but for sanity's sake, using an env file will make it easier in your local set up.